# How can specify multiple paths on LinkerBaseInputPaths Wix Property?

Tags: msbuild, wix

The PropertyGroup MSBUILD Task on WIX lets you set the LinkerBaseInputPaths property, its essentially the -b parameter for light.exe.

The property is named plural for multiple paths (which light.exe supports by multiple -b arguments), however how do we specify multiple paths on the property?

I have tried separating the paths with ";" and ",", both do not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does it not work? MSBuild turns a semi-colon-separated string into an array for the task. For example, the WiX setup project uses this:

`<BaseInputPaths>$(OutputPath_x86);$(OutputPath_x64);$(OutputPath_ia64);$(MSBuildProjectDirectory);$(WIX_ROOT)src;$(WIX_ROOT)bin;$(WIX_ROOT)src\dutil\inc;$(BaseInputPaths)</BaseInputPaths>`

Comment: You are correct, it works with semicolon, another error was causing the issue.